# Unable to sync email using imapsync

Tags: email, synchronization, imap

I'm trying to sync my emails from an old server "server2" with a new one "server1"

```
imapsync \
       --host1 imap.server1.com --user1 a@bbbccc.com --password1 fdsfdsfsfd \
       --host2 imap.server2.com --user2 a@bbbccc.com --password2 fdsfdsfds \
       --debugimap1 --debugimap2 \
       --tls1 --tls2 --debugssl 4
```

Nothing happens at all. It gets frozen. In thunderbird I use SSL/TLS and the port 993 and Normal Password. However, there're no such options in imapsync.
When I remove "--tls1 --tls2" it produces no output at all and finished in a couple of seconds.
Where is an issue?

Comment: Try specifying the servers as `imap.server1.com:993` and `imap.server2.com:993` and see if that works. Note: not tried, may still fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `--tls1 --tls2`
by `--ssl1 --ssl2`